# How can I make all text the same font size (normal text, footnotes, acknowledgements etc.)?

Tags: fonts, size

I have to submit a manuscript to a journal, and I just realized that they want every single part of the paper to be in 12 pt font. This includes tables text, footnotes, acknowledgements etc. Is there a way to force all text to be the same size?

Comment: Usually journals offer a specific style file, matching their requirements for submissions of papers. Did you have a look, if the one where you're going to submit, probably has one too?

Comment: what about math mode?

Comment: @JMP I haven't found any mention of it at all from the journal so I wouldn't count on it. I can ask them though.

Comment: if the journal doesn't provide its own document class, use one that provides a `[12pt]` option.  (i know that `article` and `amsart` do, and the article equivalent from the `koma` collection almost certainly does as well.)  that should take care of math.  in the document class code, it's usually not too difficult to find the definitions of the elements you mention; those are probably best modified by using a patch mechanism.  there's no single command that i know of to make a global change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution (let every size normal)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for example

\let\Huge\normalsize
\let\huge\normalsize
\let\LARGE\normalsize
\let\Large\normalsize
\let\large\normalsize
\let\small\normalsize
\let\footnotesize\normalsize
\let\scriptsize\normalsize
\let\tiny\normalsize
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}
bla bla\footnote{just dummy text}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not THAT is outside the box thinking!

Comment: @touhami That looks fantastic and just what I need, thanks a lot!